# error_msg=Invalid photo tag subject, error_code=322

Tags: facebook, ios, upload, photo, tagging

Using fbconnect on iPhone.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               pid, @"pid",
                               FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID, @"tag_uid",
                               @"50.0", @"x",
                               @"50.0", @"y",
                               nil];

[self.theFacebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.addTag"
                              andParams:params
                          andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                            andDelegate:self];
```

Is my FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID really wrong? In that case, how can I find the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at facebook developers page, the seccion photos/tag:

> "Currently, you cannot tag a Page in a photo using this API"

[The link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
- (void)tagPhotoWithPhotID:(NSString *)photoID {

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               photoID, @"pid",
                               @"Test Tag", @"tag_text",
                               @"50.0", @"x",
                               @"50.0", @"y",
                               nil];

[self.facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.addTag"
                              andParams:params
                          andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                            andDelegate:self];
}
```

Instead of "tag_text" key you may use "tag_uid" and supply a valid user ID as a NSString.

Comment: Yes Jeshua. It's exactly what I do right now. Actually, the problem is not "tagging a photo". I already managed doing it. The problem is to tag A PAGE instead of a user id. By placing the page id with "tag_uid" gives that error. Sorry, wrong answer.

Comment: I suppose you didn't make that at all clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Many Facebook pages are not valid tagging subjects. At this time, only pages with the primary category Person or Brand can be tagged. Specifically, Local Business cannot be tagged. Unfortunately, only the subcategory is revealed in the API and there is overlap; some subcategories are in both Local Business and Brand.

The produces strange results for ambiguous combinations like regional chains, which aren't truly a brand, but aren't truly a geo-taggable local business either.